# Multiple OR statements in IF Funtion Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need to perform an if function based on postal codes, so if postal code == a or b or c or d, ... --> area =1, if postal code is e, f, g, ... --> area = 2.
As I want to analyse this for Munich with so many postal codes, I am looking for a smoother way to not input every number.

An excample for the postal codes:

Au_Haidhausen = 81541, 81543, 81667, 81669, 81671, 81675, 81677
Bogenhausen = 81675, 81677, 81679, 81925, 81927, 81929

etc.

Current setup is literally input all elements manually...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you use a lookup table.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant. Thanks, I wasn't thinking of that one